# Как правильно задать transition при использования hover эффекта через javascript

Tags: javascript, css

```js
let avatarSimple = document.querySelector(".avatar_simple");
let avatarQuantumBreak = document.querySelector(".avatar_quantum_break");

avatarQuantumBreak.style.display = "none";

let hover = () => {
 avatarQuantumBreak.style.display = "block";
 avatarSimple.style.display = "none";
}
let normal = () => {
 avatarQuantumBreak.style.display = "none";
 avatarSimple.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.avatar {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

}
.avatar .avatar_simple img , .avatar .avatar_quantum_break img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: 5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-md-3 left_block" style="background-color: red;">
      <div class="avatar" onmouseover="hover();" onmouseout="normal();">
        <span class="avatar_simple">
          <img  src="https://certy.px-lab.com/developer/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2017/08/certy-programmer-1-195x195.png">
        </span>
        <span class="avatar_quantum_break">
          <img src="https://certy.px-lab.com/developer/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2017/08/certy-programmer-2-195x195.png">
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8" style="background-color: purple;">sfsf</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Подскажите, как правильно задать **плавный переход**`(transition)`  между картинками где используется `hover` эффект через `js`. Возможно ли такое реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Невозможно получить плавную анимацию путем смены `diplay:block/flex/inline-block`(или любой другой видимый) на `display: none`. Исключение `.fadeIn()` и `.fadeOut()` в jQuery, но оно работает плавно лишь потому, что с помощью скрипта плавно меняется прозрачность.
2. Применяйте `transition` именно к тому блоку который будет меняться, а не к его родителю.
3. Для того, чтобы анимация была плавной используют изменение заранее определенной высоты, прозрачности или `transform` например.

Как вариант, в вашем примере можно плавно менять прозрачность:

```js
let avatarSimple = document.querySelector(".avatar_simple");
let avatarQuantumBreak = document.querySelector(".avatar_quantum_break");

avatarQuantumBreak.style.opacity = "0";

let hover = () => {
  avatarQuantumBreak.style.opacity = "1";
}
let normal = () => {
  avatarQuantumBreak.style.opacity = "0";
}
```

```css
.avatar {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 195px;
}

.avatar_simple,
.avatar_quantum_break {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
  transition: opacity 5s ease-out;
}

.avatar .avatar_simple img,
.avatar .avatar_quantum_break img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-md-3 left_block" style="background-color: red;">
      <div class="avatar" onmouseover="hover();" onmouseout="normal();">
        <span class="avatar_simple">
          <img  src="https://certy.px-lab.com/developer/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2017/08/certy-programmer-1-195x195.png">
        </span>
        <span class="avatar_quantum_break">
          <img src="https://certy.px-lab.com/developer/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2017/08/certy-programmer-2-195x195.png">
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8" style="background-color: purple;">sfsf</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: я не понял у вас же не работает плавный переход @kizoso  или мне нужно смотреть вооруженным глазом?

Comment: @Spectr Наводите, картинка плавно меняется. Работает. Или что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: да работает  спасибо.